# Need a hint on calculating this $n$-th order determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

I am trying to calculate the following determinant:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_0 & -1 &  0 &  0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
a_1 &  x & -1 &  0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
a_2 &  0 &  x & -1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
a_3 &  0 &  0 &  x & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n-1} &0  & 0 & 0 & \ldots & x & -1 \\
a_n & 0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & x \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

but I don't really know how to start solving it. I've thought about multiplying the second column with $a_0$ and adding it to the first, and doing the same with the other columns (while multiplying them with $a_2,a_3,\ldots , a_n$) respectively but that doesn't seem to get me anywhere. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Expand along the first column and use the properties of "determinant of triangular matrices" to evaluate the determinant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determinant of a companion matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515679/determinant-of-a-companion-matrix)

Comment: @MartinR: This is a different matrix with a different determinant and a different way to compute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote the determinant by  $d(a_0,\ldots,a_n,x)$. Expand along the first row:
$$d(a_0,\ldots,a_n,x)=a_0x^n+d(a_1,\ldots,a_n,x).$$ So
by induction:

$$d(a_0,\ldots,a_n,x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_n.$$

**By the way**, the matrix is of size $n+1$, not $n$.

Comment: Weird. My textbook says the result is 1.

Comment: Take $n=1$:to check.